# Better idea to select unique data from table

Tags: sql, database

I am learning SQL. I want to `select` `employee` (`emp_name, emp_lname, project_name`) which has only one `project` (not more or less).

I have 3 table in database:

Tables:

```
create table employee(
    emp_id char (5) primary key,
    emp_name nvarchar(15) not null,
    emp_lname nvarchar(20)
);

create table project(
    pr_id char(5) primary key,
    project_name nvarchar(10) not null,
    project_budjet int
);

create table employee_project(
    emp_id char (5) foreign key references employee(emp_id),
    pr_id char(5) foreign key references project(pr_id),
    constraint premppk primary key(emp_id, pr_id)
);
```

I am trying to `select` only unique `emp_id` from `employee_project`.

This code gives me unique `emp_id` from `employee_project`

```
select emp_id, count(pr_id) from employee_project
    group by emp_id having count(pr_id) = 1
```

But I need `emp_id` and `pr_id` to `select` `emp_name`, `emp_lname` and `project_name`. I try to `select` `pr_id` too using `emp_id` what I have already. Code:

```
select ep.emp_id, ep.pr_id from employee_project as ep,
    (
    select emp_id, count(pr_id) from employee_project
        group by emp_id having count(pr_id) = 1
    ) CT
where CT.emp_id = ep.emp_id
```

Now I have everything to select everything what I need about these `employee` and `project`. Finally code:

```
select employee.emp_name, employee.emp_lname, project.project_name
    from employee, project, 
        (
        select ep.emp_id, ep.pr_id from employee_project as ep,
            (
            select emp_id, count(pr_id) from employee_project
                group by emp_id having count(pr_id) = 1
            ) CT
        where CT.emp_id = ep.emp_id
        ) CK
where CK.emp_id = employee.emp_id and CK.pr_id = project.pr_id
```

Is there any way to do this easily.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't think so. ``distinct`` will give me first but not unique. I don't need if it is in table one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is only one project you are looking for you can use any aggregate function in the group to get the project too. I used `min(pr_id)` but you could also use `avg()` or `max()` for instance.

After that you can join the tables to get all the other column values.

```
select e.*, p.*
from 
(
  select emp_id, min(pr_id) as pr_id
  from employee_project
  group by emp_id 
  having count(pr_id) = 1
) ep
join employee e on e.emp_id = ep.emp_id
join project p on p.pr_id = ep.pr_id
```